# Ignoring Ssl certificate warnings using HttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, http

```
httpreq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP .3. 0")
httpreq.setOption(2, 13056);
```

Is the above code supported in IE7 and higher ?? I dont think the objects can be created with that constructor.

Comment: is there any limitation against using any standard library that normalizes this for you?

Comment: I wanted to make it possible in html or JavaScript.If you have any suggestions , pls do.

Comment: Please refer this question for complete description : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904558/how-to-supress-the-ssl-certificate-warnings-using-xmlhttprequest